# Can't reach my site through amazon elastic load balancer

Tags: amazon-ec2, load-balancing

I have a few ec2 instances running and I added them to a load balancer. The load balancer gives me a public DNS name but that never reaches my ec2 instances. I can reach each ec2 instance directly from the browser. All instance show that they are healthy in the control panel. My Load balancer rules take traffic on load balancer port 80 and send it to ec2 instance port 80. Each ec2 instance takes traffic on port 80 and routes to 3000 where the apps are running. There were some similar posts on their forum, but no answer.

Comment: `All instance show that they are healthy in the control panel` .. What control panel, do you mean ELB?

Comment: I think they were having a brief service outage. It said all my instances were healthy, I couldn't reach them, came back later without touching anything  and it worked. In the meantime the aws management console failed to load twice, so I think that might be related. works fine now and I didn't change anything.